# Methods for teasing apart the influence of different time series features on a target feature?

Tags: regression, time-series, data-mining, feature-selection, python

Are there any established methods for teasing apart the influence of different time series features on a target feature?

To illustrate:

- The target: Sales volume of kittens.
- Features: Time of year, Average fluffiness, Average age, Discount factors etc...

What would be the best method of finding out how influential each feature is over the sale of kittens?

My first idea is to apply a regression model and then look at the weightings assigned to each feature. I am not sure how informative this will be though.

Is there a better way? Perhaps some established statistical method? Something Python based would be fantastic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at estimated regression coefficients would definitely be a possibility. You would need to make sure your regressors are comparable in order to have comparable coefficients, though (e.g., standardizing metric regressors, yielding "standardized" regression coefficients).

An alternative would be as follows: use a holdout sample, perhaps the last 20% of your data. Fit a very simple model to the other 80% and forecast the holdout sample with this model. Compare the forecast accuracy to the one achieved by a more complex model, where you add one explanatory variable. Do this, one at a time, for all explanatory variables you have. The variable that gives the best forecast improvement over the trivial model is the most important regressor.

Of course, this approach does not model interactions between regressors. However, you could continue comparing more complex models as to their forecast accuracy.